# Need to know if this will compile correctly with current windows SDK

Tags: c++, .net, winapi

I'm trying to create a mod for Civilization 4 and want to modify the DLL.  I have all the sources, but the game was made back when Microsoft SDK 6.0a was out.  I have a makefile for this and all the necessary libraries for compilation, but will the 8.0a SDK work for compiling this project?  The tutorial I was looking is [here](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=196283) but it seemed like a lot of needless hoops when I can just run the makefile in command line.

I have Visual Studio 2010 if there are any flags or anything I can set to make my life easier, or if there is a simple way to import this project to the .NET framework.

Comment: An honourable pursuit!

Comment: Not enough for an answer but you can't import it in to .net. The Civ expects it's plugins to be unmanaged DLL's so you must give it unmanaged DLL's. (you may be able to hack on a way to get it to work but you may run in to problems if you are not targeting the same version of .NET that any other loaded process targets (be it Civ or any other loaded plugin))